# Does chassis mid-plane provide load balancing for power supply

Tags: redundancy, power-supply-unit, blade-chassis

I am new to blade chassis management, and i want to know what is the purpose of mid plane apart from connectivity. Does it provide load balancing among the power supplies. If so does that mean it automatically ensures power supply redundancy or for redundancy some specific OR'ing circuit is needed. Appreciate any help

Comment: It would be nice to know which manufacturer's blade chassis you're talking about. I can provide specifics on HP's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shot of an [HP C7000 blade chassis](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c00804295-22%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1406647650723.876444892.492883150) midplane. It's primary function is to feed power and I/O to the individual blade servers. At this stage, power is the aggregate of the power supplies and power supply load balancing policy (e.g. n+1, n+n).

[image]

Also take a look at the description and diagrams at: [Probability of Blade Chassis Failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/454332/probability-of-blade-chassis-failure/454414#454414)

Comment: Also a nice shot of a sysadmin's boot.  Its primary function is to protect the toes when someone accidentally puts the blade chassis midplane down on the sysadmin's foot.

Comment: @MadHatter She actually dropped part of it while we were installing... so yes, boots == handy.