# Blade server backplane wiring

Tags: blade-server, wiring

Are there any blade server enclosures which have hard wired network lines on the backplane? I want be able to have separate female ethernet connectors for the NIC on every blade server in the enclosure. Because of security reasons they have to be hard wired, so there is no possibility to attack data streams from other blade servers.

Comment: There aren't too many companies that produce blades, just call them, and ask to talk to a tech sales rep.

Answer (score 3):

Blade servers are used in a variety of industries ranging from hyper-secure environments to large scale financial applications. Is there something unique about your requirements that extends beyond what's needed for other critical computing environments?

But let's use the example of an [HP C7000 enclosure](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/enclosures/)... The server downlinks are hardwired.

[image]

See: [Probability of Blade Chassis Failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/454332/probability-of-blade-chassis-failure/454414#454414)

I *think* you're asking whether there's an option for passthrough Ethernet modules to an external network switch on the blade uplink connections. If that's what you're asking, then yes, use a passthrough ethernet module and you'll be able to control the network interconnects on your own. This is available from most blade vendors.